# On ollydbg how do I find a string in code that I find on memory map?

Tags: ollydbg, debuggers

The license is saved in a txt and I can't find the string.  The code is protected as it calls to encodepointer and some modules are hidden. I'm using ollydbg 2.01 with olly ext1.8 every option activated.

I can find the license on the memory map but now how can I find it on the code, or where it compares to that license value?

I'm kinda new to ollydbg

Comment: Use breakpoints.

Answer (score 2):

In OllyDbg there is the option to set memory breakpoints. That means, you can break at the instruction which accesses this certain memory address or the region you specified.

You can set, that the breakpoint triggers at read, write and/or execute.

To set a memory breakpoint, select the area in the memory dump/map, right-click and choose Breakpoint > Memory, on Access (or what you want, probably that).

Run the program and now it should stop at the instruction where this memory is accessed.